# How do I add shapefile column to extracted data frame with terra?

Tags: r, extract, spatial, terra

I have extracted data via `terra:::extract` from a tif file using polygons in a shapefile.

```
library(terra)

tif = rast('data/snow.tif')
shape = vect('data/canada_provinces.shp')

x = extract(tif, shape, na.rm = T)
head(x)
ID       values
1        100
1        100
1        100
1        101
1        101
2        150
2        150
2        150
...
90       101
90       101
90       101
```

I would like to add the shapefile column `state`, so I get the following:

```
x = extract(tif, shape, na.rm = T, layer = 'states')

ID       values     states
1        100        AK
1        100        AK
1        100        AK
1        101        AK
1        101        AK
2        150        NT
2        150        NT
2        150        NT
...
90       101        BC
90       101        BC
90       101        BC
```

But it does not work to use the `layer` feature in the `terra:::extract`.

How can I add the actual state to the data frame created from the extract function?

Comment: When asking an R question please include example data

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your overlooking that you need to summarize the values for each polygon.

Example data

```
library(terra)
v <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))[,c("ID_2", "NAME_2")]
r <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra"))
```

Approach 1

```
vv <- extract(r, v, fun=mean, na.rm=TRUE, bind=TRUE)
```

Approach 2

```
vv$elev <- extract(r, v, fun=mean, na.rm=TRUE, ID=FALSE)[,1]
vv
# class       : SpatVector 
# geometry    : polygons 
# dimensions  : 12, 4  (geometries, attributes)
# extent      : 5.74414, 6.528252, 49.44781, 50.18162  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# source      : lux.shp
# coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
# names       :  ID_2   NAME_2 elevation  elev
# type        : <num>    <chr>     <num> <num>
# values      :     1 Clervaux     467.1 467.1
#                   2 Diekirch     333.9 333.9
#                   3  Redange     377.4 377.4
```

Approach 3

```
e <- extract(r, v, fun=mean, na.rm=TRUE)
ve <- cbind(v, e)
#Or 
values(v) <- e
```